# python: else condition is not processed completely - why?

Tags: python, gtk3

Here we have a little part from a little application.
The condition works correctly, instead of the outer `else`.

```
def setDetails(self):
    if self.found == True:
        self.btn_reset.set_sensitive(True)
        self.builder.get_object("output_ticket").set_text("GEFUNDEN: " + self.csv_row[0])
        if self.csv_row[1] == "Gesperrt!":
            self.btn_save.set_sensitive(False)
            self.builder.get_object("allert").set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_DELETE, 5)
            self.builder.get_object("output_ticket").set_text("GESPERRT!!! " + self.csv_row[0])
        elif (len(self.csv_row) > 2 and self.csv_row[2] == "1"):
            self.btn_save.set_sensitive(False)
            self.builder.get_object("allert").set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_DELETE, 5)
            self.builder.get_object("output_ticket").set_text("ALREADY CHECKED IN!!! " + self.csv_row[0])
            self.builder.get_object("check_checkedin").set_active(True)
            if len(self.csv_row) > 3:
                self.builder.get_object("output_info").set_text(self.csv_row[4])
                self.builder.get_object("text_note").set_text(self.csv_row[3])
        else:
            self.btn_save.set_sensitive(True)
            self.builder.get_object('text_note').set_sensitive(True)
            self.builder.get_object("spinner").start()
            self.builder.get_object("check_checkedin").set_sensitive(True)
            self.builder.get_object("allert").set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_YES, 5)
    else: 
        self.builder.get_object("allert").set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_NO, 5)
        self.builder.get_object("output_ticket").set_text("NICHT GEFUNDEN!!!")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.resetDetails()
```

In the outer `else`, only the last two line seems to be processed, non of the `self.builder`-stuff inside this `else` has effect. All other GTK-stuff works, only these two lines doesn't.

Does anyone see the issue?

Thanx
Johannes

Comment: **Add a counter to this function and check how many times each event has been called**

Comment: Is this part of an event handler?  I'm not familiar with GTK but in some windowing environments the screen does not change until the event handler returns.

Comment: Hello and thanks!
Thats the solution! The screen changes after leaving the event.